# Interpreting 10-YR TREAS 21/32 yield 2.913%

Tags: finance

As I see the WSJ front page, I saw 10-YR TREAS 21/32 yield 2.913%.
I know what the yield means but I don't know what the 21/32 means and how it relates to the yield. Could you please tell me?

Comment: I forget but several things determined a bond, the yield, the strike price. Also the time into the next coupon period. Determining if the bond is selling at a premium or discount. For exampke the actual interest of the coupon paid twice a year may be 1.4%. then to have the prescribed yield it must sell less than 100 dollars. If the bond was issued at 4% then it would sell at premium. So the yield is the markets current expectation for free interest. The risk free rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not seen the page, but it is likely to either be the price change or part of the price of a $10$ year benchmark US Treasury bond (probably with a par value of $\$100$ and possibly with an nominal yield of $2.75\%$)

So either the price of this benchmark bond changed by $\$21/32= \$0.65625$ or the price was $\$98\; 21/32=\$98.65625$

Why US markets use eighths or sixteenths or thirty-seconds of a dollar when they have perfectly usable tenths and twentieths and hundredths (i.e. dimes, nickels and cents) to price bonds is another question.

Comment: That’s my guess as well. Never saw that format before.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, how could you know the price was $98, not $99, $101?

Comment: You could back calculate it from 2.913% and 2.75% and 10 years, but in fact I actually looked at the current price.  I might be wrong